# VBO: Access denied to other users for the first content from the list of publishing content

Tags: users, views, nodes

While publishing a content (Alert that uses scheduler to publish its content) manually using Views bulk operation I am encountering an strange behavior.

When I selects a single or multiple Alerts to publish (Publish time has been passed ) the first Alert is not getting the right access permission in node_access table i.e.
select * from node_access where nid= 11713;
+-------+-----+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| nid | gid | realm | grant_view | grant_update | grant_delete |
+-------+-----+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 11713 | 990 | nodeaccess_author | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+-------+-----+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+

due to that after content published successfully message, when I am opening the published node from any user excepts author and admin, it is showing "You are not authorized to access this page.". But once I rebuild all the permission node_access table is filled with right permission as following
select * from node_access where nid= 11713;
+-------+-----+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| nid | gid | realm | grant_view | grant_update | grant_delete |
+-------+-----+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
| 11712 | 1 | nodeaccess_rid | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11712 | 2 | nodeaccess_rid | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11712 | 3 | nodeaccess_rid | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11712 | 4 | nodeaccess_rid | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 11712 | 5 | nodeaccess_rid | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 11712 | 6 | nodeaccess_rid | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 11712 | 990 | nodeaccess_author | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+-------+-----+-------------------+------------+--------------+--------------+
and all authorized users are now able to access this node.

This issue is only happening when node is published as bulk operation and only for first selected item. Otherwise if page is published automatically by Cron run or it is in any position other then 1st in the list of bulk operation then its access permission are setting correctly and everything is working fine.

Comment: Is your VBO action based on core publish action or is it provided by scheduler?  If the action is provided as part of a contributed (non-core) module, maybe check the issue queue for that module?

Comment: I have installed VBO as a contrib module and It uses using scheduler to publish the content. have checked the Scheduler and VBO issue queue but have't got any related post. What next ?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know.  Sounds like it might be an issue with Scheduler... perhaps make an issue on the queue for people who know more about that module.